# Separate Continent Shapefiles

Tags: geospatial

I am looking for polygon shapefiles of 7 continents available separately (Africa, South America,North America,Asia,Australia,Antarctica,Greenland). I have got single polygon shapefile for all the continent which I am not interested in.

Hope someone can share the sites where I can get these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find them [here](https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/continents-of-the-world%40public/map/?location=2,-7.25298,19.0676&basemap=jawg.light) and download them as a shapefile (or other format) in the Export tab.

Hope this helps

Comment: The link is dead